# OSGi DS: Why are exceptions thrown by binding methods only logged?

Tags: osgi, declarative-services

Why is it spec to only log an exception thrown from a binding method?

I would expect that the component would not activate in this case.

How should exceptions thrown from binding methods be handled to ensure the component is set up correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just because the binding of a service reference throws an exception does not necessarily mean the component cannot be activated. Since the component is aware of the exception (after all, it's the binding method that threw it), it can be implemented in such a way that it can still be activated, e.g. by falling back on a default value or by providing limited services.

Binding methods should not throw any exception anyway, unlike activation methods that can make the activation fail.

**Reference:**

OSGi 112.5.7: "If a bind method throws an exception, SCR must log an error message containing the exception with the Log Service, if present, but the activation of the component configuration does not fail."

Comment: How would the component be aware of the exception.  Seem like it just gets swallowed by the service component runtime.

Comment: @Dave H The binding method can `try/catch` if it expects an exception. It can even rethrow it if it's the only sensible strategy.

Comment: What if the binding method doesn't expect the exception (RuntimeException)?

Comment: @Dave H: I think binding methods are not supposed to do anything complex, so there shouldn't be any exception. Think of them as setters, and do the complex things in the activation method.

Comment: What about the case where the binding method is dynamic and can get called after the activation method has been called.  That's where I more have the issue.

Comment: there is also the case where you have a simple one liner setter method that throws an exception due to type mismatch issues and the component is still activated, seems cumbersome to have to add a try/catch to every single binding method